# Selenium stale element exception (found when running tests and not while debugging)

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver

I am getting stale element exception when I run the code. However while debugging I do not get this exception. 
Here is my piece of code. Can anybody help me ? thanks

```
      public static bool CheckListFilterResult(IList<IWebElement> gridColumns, IList<IWebElement> gridRows, string filterColumn, List<string> filters)
    {
        bool checkResult = false;
        {
            int filterColumnIndex = GetColumnIndex(gridColumns, filterColumn);
           if (gridRows.Count > 0 )
           {
                foreach (IWebElement row in gridRows)
                {
                    TestManager.Doc.Step("before bool match");
                   bool filterMatch = filters.Contains(row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[filterColumnIndex].Text.Trim());
                    if (filterMatch)
                    {
                        checkResult = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checkResult = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            return checkResult;
        }
    }
```

Comment: On what line does the exception occur?

Comment: bool filterMatch = filters.Contains(row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[filterColumnIndex].Text.Trim());

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, that line is the first line where you access something from the `rows` collection. My guess is that it has something to do with that. Did you pull the `rows` collection, then apply a filter, then call this function? If so, that's probably the problem. You need to apply the filter, then pull the `rows` collection, then call the function.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your IWebElement row was updated by javascript while you were running your selenium code.

As explained here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp, Stale Element Reference Exception happens when the object on the UI may have been refreshed but you are trying to access the same object. So even if the row is visible to the user, it may have been updated/replaced by javascript, then it is a different object.

The reason why it happens only occassionaly but not always could be that when you run in debug mode, you are stopping at each line of your selenium code, but javascript code doesnt stop, so the element on the UI was already refreshed, then your selenium code gets a fresh copy of the IWebElement row.

There are several possible ways of fixing this problem.

1. try to catch StaleElementReferenceException, if it happens, then redo whatever you are trying to do.
2. you can do: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(row));

Hope it helps